# Getting rid of negative-cost edges in min-cost max-flow algorithmically

Tags: network-flow

I have a min-cost max-flow problem. The designed network (without cycles) gives correct results using cycle cancelling, but it is way too slow. I would like to get rid of negative edges so that I can use successive shortest path.

Is there a universal way how to transform a flow network without cycles?